# Stackexchange meta tags

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't large popular sites such as SO use keyword and description meta headers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13995/why-dont-large-popular-sites-such-as-so-use-keyword-and-description-meta-headers)

I noticed that Stackoverflow and the other Stackexchange websites have very few of the expected meta tags (keywords, description, etc) in their html.   The stackexchange sites consistently rank pretty well so I was wondering why that might be.

Answer (score 4):

> Because the keywords meta tag was so
>   often abused, many years ago Google
>   began disregarding the keywords meta
>   tag.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html

They sometimes use the description tag (see that article). The stackexchange sites rank well because of seo goodness like lots of incoming links and useful original content.

Comment: +1 Also see: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-meta-keywords-worth-the-effort

Answer (score 1):

Most meta tags are completely useless:

- **keywords** is not used in ranking by Google and has almost no value (if not zero value) in other search engines.
- **description** *is* used by search engines but because SO's content is entirely user-generated it's impossible to include a relevant meta-description that doesn't just repeat what's already on the page.
- **robots** should be replaced by the more reliable robots.txt.
- **language** is [pretty much ignored](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/how-can-i-prevent-google-mistakenly-offering-to-translate-a-page/5073#5073) by search engines. Regardless, the correct way to specify language is to use the `lang` attribute.

All the other tags are pretty much fluff that should either be set with HTTP headers (e.g. expires), visible on the page itself (e.g. copyright, author), or removed entirely (e.g. generator).